# How to extract data attribute that contains a json string using javascript (no JQuery)

Tags: javascript, json, custom-data-attribute

I have the following element below that has a data attribute that contains a json string.  I am unable to retrieve the json string, instead it is returning the opening bracket of the json string.  Please see below.

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('elem').getAttribute('data-hashtags'));
```

```html
<input id="elem" data-hashtags="["john","barclays-statements","hmrc","laptop","tesco","meat","dinner","drinks","food","cleaning-products","taxi","lunch"]">
```

Comment: `data-hashtags='["john","barclays-statements","hmrc","laptop","tesco","meat","dinner","drinks","food","cleaning-products","taxi","lunch"]'` try this.

Comment: @ÖzgürCanKaragöz if you would  like to put that as an answer i can accept it.  thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mixed up the quotes.

It should be like this:

```
<input id="elem" data-hashtags="['john','barclays-statements','hmrc','laptop','tesco','meat','dinner','drinks','food','cleaning-products','taxi','lunch']">
```

Not like this:

```
<input id="elem" data-hashtags="["john","barclays-statements","hmrc","laptop","tesco","meat","dinner","drinks","food","cleaning-products","taxi","lunch"]">
```

As you can see in the syntax highlighting, attributes are marked orange (e. g. `data-hashtags`), and values of attributes are blue (e. g. `elem`). The values of your attribute are also marked orange, that means they get interpreted as attributes themselves.

That's because after `"` the value "starts". With your second `"`, the value "ends", so the value is just a bracket `[`. According to that, the next attribute would be `john` with the value of `,` (missing `=` here, so it would be invalid anyways), and so on.